# What does it mean for a set-valued mapping to "take values" with [INSERT PROPERTIES]?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, control-theory, set-valued-analysis

I've been studying set-valued analysis and I realize that I haven't been paying very close attention to some of the language being used, and I could use some clarification.

Here is an example from *Discontinuous Dynamical Systems: A Tutorial on Solutions, Nonsmooth Analysis, and Stability* by Jorge Corte:

**Proposition S2:** Let $F:[0,\infty )\times\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ be locally bounded and *take nonempty, compact, and convex values*. Assume that, for each $t\in\mathbb{R}$, the set-valued map $x\mapsto F(t,x)$ is upper semicontinuous, and, for each $x\in\mathbb{R}^d$, the set-valued map $t\mapsto F(t,x)$ is measurable. Then, for all $(t_0,x_0)\in[0,\infty )\times\mathbb{R}^d$, there exists a Caratheodory solution of $\dot{x}(t)=X(t,x(t))$ with initial condition $x(t_0)=x_0$.

So, when Cortes says, "...take nonempty, compact, and convex values", what does he mean specifically?

Comment: No, "value" means output, especially when used with the verb "to take."  Also, $\mathbb{B}$ cannot be an input to $F$.

Comment: So the set that is the output from the must satisfy those conditions. As for $\mathbb{B}$ being an input, let's try to forget that I ever said that hahaha. But thanks for clarifying that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The codomain of $F$ is a set of subsets of $\mathbb{R}^d$. Then

> take nonempty, compact, and convex *values*

means that the sets that turn up in the image of $F$ have those properties.

Your guess that this phrase describes the input to $F$ is wrong.

Comment: Great thanks, this clarifies things for me.